# how to restrict updation of another column when one column is being updated mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i have table called post_data having username,email,pass,cam_name,upd_date(of type datatime) fields in that. but the problem is when i insert username, email pass into the table that upd_date(datatime) is updated with current data and time. how can i restrict that ...

I even change the datatype form DATETIME to TIMESTAMP

No use..still it stores current date and time when i update only certain columns.

can any tell me ...

[image: this is my table structure in mysql database]

[image]

Comment: If your table is called `post_data` you should probably rename it to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the default `datetime` for that column. You need to **[`alter`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)** the column.

```
 alter table post_data alter column upd_date drop default;
```

If your column doesn't accept `NULL`, then it will implicitly set default value. You need to alter you table to allow `null`.

[**Data Type Default Values**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html)

> If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL
>   determines the default value

```
ALTER TABLE post_data MODIFY upd_date datetime null;
```

Comment: i execute that query, but it stores 000000000000 in that upd_date field.

Comment: @lohithkumar could you post the table definition ?

Comment: i post table definition also @ravi bro . table consists of only record.

Comment: @lohithkumar It seems like your column are not nullable. You need to make it nullable.

Comment: ok bro it works well, but small issue is there... if i retrieve cam_name, cam_img, cam_rent in another page before data insertion of that particluar fields.. it doesn't seems nyc...because write query like this php..

Comment: @lohithkumar I din't get you. Could you post a new question with your problem and close this post by accepting it ?

Comment: query in php page
  ----------------

$stmt = $index_home->getDetails();

 
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)

 {
 
 
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

 
 {
  
 extract($row);

       }

?>

Comment: getDetails implentation
  -----------------------


 public function getDetails()
 {
 
 try
 {
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT userID, user_name, cam_name, cam_model, cam_rent, cam_img, mobile FROM post_data ORDER BY userID DESC');
 $stmt->execute();
 return $stmt;
 }
 catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155257/discussion-between-lohith-kumar-and-ravi).

Comment: @lohithkumar it is not clear what you are asking. You need to post clearer question to get your problem solved otherwise it will take a year to understand your question.

Comment: @lohithkumar Chatting won't help until you describe your problem with error or screenshot. You should post new question.